# Updating admin-on-rest version

Tags: admin-on-rest

In my package.json it says I have a admin-on-rest installed 0.9.4 version. We want to update the version of it. How to do it? I have tried using npm update but seems not working. I wanted to add the feature for custom toolbar.

Comment: There is more to updating than just running npm install. Things might break. Proceed with caution. There is a major version upgrade from 0.9 to 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the version inside your `package.json` file. Last one is `1.3.2` then run `npm install` again